# Quote not being replaced by escape character

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to write a JavaScript RegEx that properly adds escape characters to all the single and double quote characters in a string. For example, if I have the following string:

```
"Hey, how's it going? You're really good at this!"
```

The code should transform that string to:

```
"Hey, how\'s it going? You\'re really good at this!"
```

Below is my code:

```
var testString = "Hey, how's it going? You're really good at this!";
testString = testString.replace(/'/g, '\'').replace(/"/g, '\"');
alert(testString);
```

The quotes are currently not being replaced by an escape character.

Comment: `"\'" === "'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your

```
.replace(/'/g, '\'')
.replace(/"/g, '\"');
```

replacement strings still only have a single character in them:

```js
const str1 = '\'';
const str2 = '\"';
console.log(str1, str2);
console.log(str1.length, str2.length);
```

```
\'
```

and

```
\"
```

in a string literal only indicate unnecessarily escaped characters: `\'` is not an escape sequence (like `\n`), so it's equivalent to `'`.

Put another backslash next to the backslash to indicate a literal backslash:

```
testString.replace(/'/g, '\\'').replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

You can also use `String.raw` to avoid having to type the backslashes twice, but it's not worth it for something this short:

```
testString.replace(/'/g, String.raw`\'`).replace(/"/g, String.raw`\"`);
```